# Pytesseract detecting scrambled words

Tags: python, discord.py, opencv, image-recognition, python-tesseract

I have a simple pytesseract script that runs inside a discord bot to detect text from an image. However when given [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quY2H.png), it returns `['ESC es Sum Ls a ns ay', 'on', '', 'Sa eon', '', 'Lape een ne eeren eee eserees', '', 'omeereer ee ate erence ecco at arte', '', 'Ue te eect eet rac contac', '', ' ', '', 'ree Cee ed', 'ema eect eens', '\x0c']` 
My code is

```
im = cv2.imread(attachment.filename)
            config = ('-l eng --oem 1 --psm 3')
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config=config)
            text = text.split('\n')
```

Comment: Try inverting so text is black on white background. Also go goggling for _tesseract improve recognition_ because you might need to make the characters in the image larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to barny for this answer but what I did was

```
            image = Image.open(attachment.filename)
            if image.mode == 'RGBA':
                r, g, b, a = image.split()
                rgb_image = Image.merge('RGB', (r, g, b))

                inverted_image = PIL.ImageOps.invert(rgb_image)

                r2, g2, b2 = inverted_image.split()

                final_transparent_image = Image.merge('RGBA', (r2, g2, b2, a))

                final_transparent_image.save(attachment.filename)

            else:
                inverted_image = PIL.ImageOps.invert(image)
                inverted_image.save(attachment.filename)
            im = cv2.imread(attachment.filename)
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
```

Which basically inverts the colors/colours and changes it into RGBA. I got perfect readings from this!